# wxPython: How to clear default text in TextCtrl with one click

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am making a GUI using wxPython, and I have a text box that requires user input:

```
self.boxQuantity = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value="Enter quantity", pos=(100, 150), size=(100, 30))
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.getQuantity, self.boxQuantity)
```

I want the user to be able to click on the text box, and "Enter quantity" to disappear immediately, instead of having to use backspace. Is this possible?

I'm using Windows 10, Python 2.7.9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want

```
def toggle1(evt):
    if self.boxQuantity.GetValue() == "Enter quantity":
        self.boxQuantity.SetValue("")
    evt.Skip()
def toggle2(evt):
    if self.boxQuantity.GetValue() == "":
        self.boxQuantity.SetValue("Enter quantity")
    evt.Skip()    

self.boxQuantity.Bind(wx.EVT_FOCUS,toggle1)
self.boxQuantity.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS,toggle2)
```

its probably better to create a subclass

```
import wx
class PlaceholderTextCtrl(wx.TextCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.default_text = kwargs.pop("placeholder", "")
        wx.TextCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.OnKillFocus(None)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.OnFocus)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.OnKillFocus)

    def OnFocus(self, evt):
        self.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        if self.GetValue() == self.default_text:
            self.SetValue("")
        evt.Skip()

    def OnKillFocus(self, evt):
        if self.GetValue().strip() == "":
            self.SetValue(self.default_text)
            self.SetForegroundColour(wx.LIGHT_GREY)
        if evt:
            evt.Skip()

# then sometime later...

self.text_entry1 = PlaceHolderTextCtrl(self,-1,placeholder="Enter Value")
```

something like that at least ...

Answer (score 10):

I know that this question is old, but wxPython now (4.1) has a new `SetHint` function for a `TextCtrl`:

```py
text = wx.TextCtrl(self)
text.SetHint('First name')  # This text is grey, and disappears when you type
```