# Textbox does not automatically delete self

Tags: python, user-interface

I want the textbox to automatically delete previous output so I can type a full sentence without every letter printing to the textbox. However, it repeats itself going all the way down, so when I hit my save button it records every line to my clipboard.

I have tried using the Tkinter text delete: text.delete(1.0,END). It does not delete anything, however.

```
class ExamplePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(3000,2000))
        self.cipherText = wx.StaticText(self, label="Ciphered Text: ", pos=(20, 30))

    #A multiline TextCtrl- Shows the events in the program. 
    #I think this might be where the problem is but I do not know how to 
    #get it to only print once, perhaps after the user hits "enter" or something.
        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(300,20), size=(200,300), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
```

…

```
        self.encrypt = wx.StaticText(self, label="Encryptor: ", pos=(20,60))
        self.encryptEdit = wx.TextCtrl(self, value="", pos=(150, 60), size=(140,-1))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.EncText, self.encryptEdit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.EncChar, self.encryptEdit)
```

…

```
    def EncText(self,event):
        result = ''
        message = event.GetString()
        for i in range(0, len(message)):
            result = result + chr(ord(message[i]) - 2)
        result = result.replace(chr(30), ' ')
        print(result + '\n\n')
        self.logger.AppendText(result + '\n\n')
```

As described above, my goal is to have it empty the textbox whenever a new keystroke is made so that it doesn't repeat going all the way down. This is what it currently looks like: [Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIR9F.png)

Comment: `wxPython` and `tkinter` are two different modules and there is no sense to use tkinter's delete() in `wxPython`

Comment: I had thought you could use them together to make one cohesive system. Is this not true?

Comment: you can't use tkinter's widgets in wxpython and wxpython's widgets in tkinter. The same with other GUI modules - like PyQt, PySize, PyGTK, etc. You can't use one GUI in other GUI.

Comment: instead of `.ApppendText(result + '\n\n')` try `.SetValue(result + '\n\n')`. It should replace text in `TextCtrl`

Comment: using Google: `wxpython texctrl clear text` I found on Stackoverflow: [wxPython: How to clear default text in TextCtrl with one click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379079/wxpython-how-to-clear-default-text-in-textctrl-with-one-click)

Comment: Thank you, the setValue worked! Also thank you for informing me about the two GUI packages. I appreciate it greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.ApppendText(result + '\n\n')` try `.SetValue(result + '\n\n')`. It should replace text in `TextCtrl`

---

See doc for [wx.TextCtrl](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextCtrl.html). 
`wx.TextCtrl` is based on `wx.TextEntry` so some functions for `TextCtrl` you can find  in doc for [wx.TextEntry](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextEntry.html). There is also `SetValue()`.